# Django AutoField with primary_key vs default pk

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, primary-key

I am curious about Django database model pk.

Is there any difference this

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

between this?

```
class Category(models.Model):
   category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Are the same things `AutoField with primary_key` and `default pk`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the difference is, the column name in the database for the primary key is `category_id` and in the second case is `id`.

One way you can make the second example emulate the first one is:

```
class Category(models.Model):
   category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   @property
   def category_id(self):
       return self.id
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield),

> AutoField
>
> An IntegerField that automatically increments according to available IDs. You usually won’t need to use this directly; a primary key field will automatically be added to your model if you don’t specify otherwise

Comment: If only difference is coloumn name, no problem for me. But I like `AutoField` more. Easier to filter for future I think.

Comment: Django inserts an auto field  for you if you do not specify  the primary key.  Check the link in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The difference is **field name**.

For example, I definded **the model "Category"** with **the field "category_id"**:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then, run this command below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Now, I opened **"db.sqlite3"** then the field name is **"category_id"**:

[image]

Next, I definded **the model "Category"** without **the field "category_id"**:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
   category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then, run this command below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Now, I opened **"db.sqlite3"** then the field name is **"id"**:

[image]